# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler when add tomahawk-1.1.11

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

added tomahawk-1.1.11.jar file to WEB-INF/lib of my web app and get error message:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:   
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link 
org/apache/myfaces/custom/aliasbean/AliasBeanTagHandler

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler 
from [Module "deployment.appFramework.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

stack trace:

```
10:44:14,813 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].
[/appFramework]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event 
to listener instance of class 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener:java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/myfaces/custom/aliasbean
/AliasBeanTagHandler (Module "deployment.appFramework.war:main" from Service Module 
Loader)
at 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) 
[jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart
(StandardContext.java:3368)
[jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) 
[jbossweb-7.0.1
.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at   
org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) 
[jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService
(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run
(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
[:1.6.0_30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)   
[:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/myfaces/custom/aliasbean
/AliasBeanTagHandler (Module "deployment.NAISFramework.war:main" from Service Module 
Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:401)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:590)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:183)
at  
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked
(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
at  
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass
(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:332) 
[jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
at 
com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass
(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:311) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
at 
com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent
(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:568) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-
SNAPSHOT]
at  
com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags
(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:361) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-
SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary
(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:314) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-
SNAPSHOT]
at   
com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process
(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:263) [jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-
SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363)
[jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
at    
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225) 
[jsf-impl-2.1.3-b02-jbossorg-2.jar:2.1.3-SNAPSHOT]
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [:1.6.0_30]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)   
[:1.6.0_30]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:397)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler from [Module
"deployment.appFramework.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked
(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked
(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
    at   
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass
(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
    at    
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
    ... 28 more

10:44:14,907 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] 
(MSC service thread 1-7)   Error listenerStart
10:44:14,907 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] 
(MSC service thread 1-7)   Context [/appFramework] startup failed due to previous 
errors
10:44:14,907 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (MSC   
service   
thread 1-7) JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP 
container.

10:44:14,922 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-7) registering web context: 
/appFramework
10:44:14,922 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final "Arc" 
started in 287
50ms - Started 454 of 511 services (57 services are passive or on-demand)
10:44:14,969 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)   
Deployed "appFramework.war"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tomahawk 1.1.11](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html) is available in 2 flavors:

- [Tomahawk 1.1.11 for JSF 1.2](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/tomahawk12-1.1.11-bin.zip)
- [Tomahawk 1.1.11 for JSF 2.0](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/tomahawk20-1.1.11-bin.zip)

This exception indicates that you're attempting to install "Tomahawk 1.1.11 for JSF 1.2" on an environment which only supports JSF 2.0. Remove those wrong Tomahawk JARs, download the right Tomahawk version and drop its JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` instead.